# Wireless connection slow on a Dell Studio with an Intel Centrino N 1000

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell, intel-wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless with WEP extremely slow on an Acer Timeline 4810T with a Centrino Wireless-N 1000](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81156/wireless-with-wep-extremely-slow-on-an-acer-timeline-4810t-with-a-centrino-wirel)

I have a Dell Studio, and just installed via CD the 12.04 LTS version. The problem is that the wireless connection is ultra slow, and that didn't happen with 11.04 or Windows 7.

How can i fix it? Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it occur when the laptop runs on battery but not on AC?

Comment: I also have this problem with my laptop.  Wireless speed is extremely slow on AC and on battery. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 (upgraded from 11.10). Hardware is Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN, REV=0x6C.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/81156/wireless-with-wep-extremely-slow-on-an-acer-timeline-4810t-with-a-centrino-wirel