# Wireless connects, but no internet access

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet

I have a new installation on a new Dell laptop (i7 8GB RAM). I find my network and successfully connect to it, but then when I open a browser, it acts like I don't have an internet connection. Please help.

Comment: The only way i managed to connect to Internet was by removing all security methods (and by plugging the Ethernet cable). Thats weird problem...

Answer (score 1):

I always find with network issues you want to try pinging in one order or the other:

*ping localhost*

```
    ping 127.0.0.1
```

*ping you local gateway (normally 192.168.0.1)*

```
    ping 192.168.X.X
```

*ping an IP external to your local netowrk (Google public DNS)*

```
    ping 8.8.8.8
```

*ping a domain to see if you can resolve a domain*

```
    ping google.com
```

depending on which of these work it will help you track down the problem, if you can't ping your router your network isn't up as advised, if you can ping further then you know you're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the security method of your router from WEP to WPA/WPA2. I had this issue but after changing the security the wireless connection worked fine for me. (Yes this solution aaplies to you if you are using WEP security)

I got idea of changing the security method from this link - [Wireless with WEP extremely slow on an Acer Timeline 4810T with a Centrino Wireless-N 1000](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81156/wireless-with-wep-extremely-slow-on-an-acer-timeline-4810t-with-a-centrino-wirel) and it worked

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work for me :\