# Centrino Wireless-N 1000 takes forever to connect and keeps asking for password

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

A few days ago I started having this problem.

When I tried to connect to any WiFi Connection it would stay connecting forever, and after a minute or so it would ask me for the password again.

The strange thing is that this happened out of nowhere, I did not install any new drivers or anything like that. After this happened I decided to uninstall ubuntu and install it again ("inside windows") but the problem is still there. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 2c:27:d7:aa:e4:7d
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:50 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:1e:64:09:9c:58
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-23-generic-pae firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:52 memory:c4500000-c4501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1.2
       logical name: eth1
       serial: ee:85:2f:7d:80:96
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth ip=172.20.10.2 link=yes multicast=yes
```

- I tried both lines to disable N networking but it didn't work for me: [Wireless with WEP extremely slow on an Acer Timeline 4810T with a Centrino Wireless-N 1000](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81156/wireless-with-wep-extremely-slow-on-an-acer-timeline-4810t-with-a-centrino-wirel)

Comment: Could there be any problem with my wireless driver? My computer worked just fine until it suddenly stopped working, and now even if I try reinstalling Ubuntu it won't work (tried with 12.04 and 11.10)

Comment: I've had similar problems in the past (not with N).  Not sure exactly how I fixed it, but it involved connecting to the router/gateway with an Ethernet cable so I could get to 192.168.1.1 which is the router configuration.  One thing that probably shouldn't have made any difference, but seemed to help, was retrieving the password from the router in hex and using that to signon to wireless.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll try that tonight. I do have access connecting directly to the router.

Comment: Can I Bump this somehow?

Comment: You might want to try posting on http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/ assuming your computer is a notebook.

Comment: It's worth tailf-ing /var/log/syslog as it tries to connect; that might give you some idea as to what is going on.

Comment: have you tried: edit connections & deleting your (wireless) connection & adding it again?

Comment: No connection works, not my university's, nor the connection at my place..I don't think that could solve the problem, nevertheless I haven't tried that :/

Comment: After not using ubuntu for a few months, somehow the problem is gone. I hope it doesn't happen again, anyways thanks everybody who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

try to tune the buffer size

`sudo echo 83886080 > /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max`

Comment: Could you please make your answer more complete and give some more information about this fix?