# Updating Realtek wireless driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

so I've had problems with my wireless for a few months and now I really have to use linux to start programming again so I really need to get this fixed.
I've been searching the web about my problem and appareantly the problem is the driver, so I'm trying to update it, but I can't seem to be able to do so.

I've been following this tutorial: https://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/

But I'm stuck where I have to add the new driver to the kernel with the following command:

```
root@ubuntu:~/r8168-8.032.00# insmod src/r8168.ko
```

insmod: error inserting 'src/r8168.ko': -1 File exists

I've tried every "path" i can think of and I keep getting errors when I try to add the new driver. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Also, for more information about my computer (in case you need its necessary) everything's in this link: [Centrino Wireless-N 1000 takes forever to connect and keeps asking for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155104/centrino-wireless-n-1000-takes-forever-to-connect-and-keeps-asking-for-password)

Comment: That first link is for an ethernet card not a wireless card, so updating that will not likely fix your problem. Maybe updating your original question with a link where you found out that it might be a driver problem might help?

Comment: I didn't really "find out" I supposed that could be the only problem left as I have tried almost everything and nothing seems to work. I'm starting to use Ruby on rails and it works better in linux than in windows, which is why now I really feel I should get this problem fixed :/

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with another Realtek adapter RTL8187SE (using `r8187se` as the default driver provided by ubuntu). Using the windows (xp) driver with `ndiswrapper-1.58rc1` resolved the problem.  I couldn't use the official `ndiswrapper` or `ndisgtk` (v1.57 from ubuntu repo).  For details see [the solution in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214085/need-a-few-reboots-to-connect-to-wireless/216123#216123).